# I would like to plot historical data (overlay false) INTO THE FUTURE

Tags: time, pine-script, future, series

For example, suppose I wanted to plot like this:

`plot(close[500])`

This would give me the close of 500 bars ago, right?  But the indicator would stop at the current bar.  How might I continue to project the plot into the future?

So that I might have 500 bars from the past, AND the NEXT 100 bars also plotted?

Bear in mind that in this case the NEXT 100 bars of the series still occurred far in the past; starting from `close[500]`, projecting out to the 100th bar would be approaching `close[400]`, if you can follow me...  visualize this...

Any thoughts?  Thank you...

Comment: As you can probably surmise, the goal if to overlay historical data onto the current chart, with the the historical data not stopping at the current bar, but continuing for X number of bars into the future...

Comment: So write a forecast function - perhaps something simple like the next value is based on the previous 3 etc etc

Comment: I don't want to generate some kind of moving average.  I want the actual historical data.  close[500] for every bar up until the present bar.  But then, beginning with the NEXT bar, i want close[499], close[498], etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset` parameter with negative numbers also:

```
plot(close, offset = -100)
```

This will plot the close price of 100 bars in the future on current bar

Comment: The problem with that is that I will be getting the same close[500] data, only it will show up 100 bars later. I want close[500] on todays bar, and close[400] 100 bars later..  (Does that make sense?  Each bar in the future will still be plotting close[500] relative to it's position)

Comment: TBH I've haven't fully understood your question then. Let's say the current bar has a bar_index of 1000. What do you want to plot on that bar? The `close` price of `bar_index` 500 (500 bars ago)? Where do you want to plot the `close` price of `bar_index` 600 (400 bars ago)? On the same current bar?

Comment: i want every bar, past present and future, to have close[500] plotted. this is easy for past and present.  `plot(close[500])` does the trick.  The problem is extending this X bars into the future...   (I understand that X must be less than 500, or I would end up with a circular reference.)

Comment: There are some limitations to the `plot` function. You can try `plot(close[250], offset = 250)` to plot `close[500]` on all bars (past, present and future)

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/frusD7gR/  shows a historical overlay from several years ago on the present chart, in blue.  But as you can see, the history "ends" at the current bar.  I want to extend the history a few weeks/months into the future...  The code used for the example is simply `plot(close[500])`

Comment: Thank you Mr Statler for your thoughtful suggestions.  Cutting the value in half seems reasonable, but radically changes the history being plotted.  It seems clear there is not an easy solution.  In fact pinescript may not allow it to be done at all, given the potential for a circular reference.  I'll keep researching.  Thanks again.

Comment: As mentioned, there are some limitations. The code `plot(close[250], offset = 250)` is workaround by splitting the history reference with the offset parameter. It works great here on the TQQQ ticker 1D timeframe and plots all the values into the future also

Comment: I stand corrected.  I don't quite understand why, but your example code `plot(close[250], offset = 250)`  does what I was looking for.  Well done!  Many thanks!